# JavaScript: detect if cookies are disabled and redirect to an error page

Tags: javascript, cookies

So if cookies are disabled execute `document.location = /enable-cookies.aspx`. I have this code so far:

```
var cookiesEnabled = navigator.cookieEnabled;
```

And what should I do next? Maybe write a cookie and check if it's value is sent? Or should I just use an `if()` statement?

```
if (cookiesEnabled){ // or something like this

}
```

Then at last redirect to the file "/enable-cookies.aspx" if cookies are disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following `JavaScript code` inside your `<head></head>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function detect()
    {
        if (navigator.cookieEnabled)
        {
            // Do something else, maybe?
        }
        else
        {
           document.location = '/enable-cookies.aspx';
        }
    }
</script>
```

And then add the following JavaScript event in your `<body></body>` tag:

```
<body onload="detect();"><!-- ...Some HTML code... --></body>
```